# Is there an optimal version of NOOBS for each Pi model?

Tags: noobs, operating-systems

Is the most recent version of NOOBS appropriate for all models of Pi, or does each on have an optimal version?

I'm focussing optimality on speed only (and foregoing security) as I'm mainly concerned on getting the best out of some older models without internet connections just now (model 1B and Zero).

Comment: Noobs is just the installer. Which Operating System are you after? If it’s just Raspbian don’t bother with Noobs. Install the Raspbian image direct to the sd card with Etcher. There are no optimum versions of Raspbian for specific Pi’s.

Comment: Of course, it is ultimately the OS I'm interested in, but using NOOBS as a proxy for this as a convenience of installation. The version I currently have has a number of OS choices, which I quite enjoy having the options of, even if I haven't explored them all yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most recent Noobs should work on all Pi's. There is no optimal version for different Pi's.

Noobs release notes: https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/releases

Comment: Thanks, I read from this that there would be no advantage to install a newer version than I already have then, is that correct?

Comment: A new version won't give you any performance enhancement. New version will be required for compatibility with the latest Pi's. I've personally never used Noobs - always install os images directly to sd card. Noobs will take up some disk space.